# Three.js: Compute composite scaling factors for a child mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

I wish to click on any target (mesh object) and attach a standard size sphere mesh object to it.
If the target mesh has been scaled other than (1,1,1) the following code will adjust the scaling of the attached marker sphere so that the plotted radius of the latter remains standard.

```
//...attach marker sphere to clicked object

        intersected_object.add ( marker_sphere );

        var positionV3 = new THREE.Vector3(); 
        positionV3 = intersected_object.worldToLocal( intersects[ 0 ].point );
        xxx = F_Position_Copy_from_vector3_to_Object3D( positionV3, marker_sphere );

        marker_sphere.scale.x = 1/ intersected_object.scale.x;
        marker_sphere.scale.y = 1/ intersected_object.scale.y;
        marker_sphere.scale.z = 1/ intersected_object.scale.z;
```

However if the clicked-on target mesh is a child of a parent mesh (or a child of a parent Object3D) and the parent has non-unitary scaling then it will be neccessary to factor the parent scaling into the marker sphere scaling.  Things get even more complicated if the target is a grand-child.

An alternative way would be to find out the most senior (non-Scene) object in the target's "ancestry hierarchy" and then define the attached marker sphere position and scaling parameters relative to the respective values of the senior object.

**QUESTION**

So is there a simple/robust way to find the "senior" object in the ancestry hierarchy of a mesh object?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for a sample of different objects..

```
//... find senior parent (non-Scene) object
var thisOb = intersected_object; //...default
var done = false;
while ( done == false)
{
    if ( thisOb.parent != "" ) //... not undefined
    { 
        if ( thisOb.parent.type == "Scene" ) //... got to the top
        {
            done = true;
            var senior_object = thisOb;
        }
        else
        {
            thisOb = thisOb.parent
        }
    }
    else  //... no parentOb
    {
     alert ('ehhh???');
     done = true;
    }
}//... end while

//... attach sphere to object at click point on object
senior_object.add ( marker_sphere );

//... position marker sphere relative to clicked object
var positionV3 = new THREE.Vector3(); 
positionV3 = senior_object.worldToLocal( intersects[ 0 ].point );
xxx = SOW_F_Position_Copy_from_vector3_to_Object3D( positionV3, marker_sphere );

marker_sphere.scale.x = 1/ senior_object.scale.x;
marker_sphere.scale.y = 1/ senior_object.scale.y;
marker_sphere.scale.z = 1/ senior_object.scale.z;
```